# Wireless mesh network based on cheap consumer routers

Tags: networking, wireless, mesh-network

I wanted to know if any such system already exists for the average open-source user. With all of the net neutrality arguments around and with the cost of broadband likely to go up in the future. It seems like a good idea for an open-source protocol that allows standard consumer routers to operate together and form a mesh network with other consumer routers close by.

Likely possible that with enough nodes in close enough proximity and a good abstraction we could get something good going.

Comment: IEEE 802.11s and http://www.open80211s.org/ ?

Comment: This looks like something that should go on Serverfault

Comment: I dont see how, given it would be a programming project,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use WDS nodes (like a repeater, kinda).

I use it in my Buffalo AirStation with DD-WRT installed (any router that can load DD-WRT would work).

www.dd-wrt.com

Not sure on the scalability of it though.  And the APs would have to be in reach of each other.  They could run on separate SSIDs though.

Edit: here's the DD-WRT Wiki page about WDS: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WDS

Answer (score 2):

WDS is not meant for and will not scale to more than a few nodes.

There has been extensive work on mesh routing protocols such as [BATMAN-ADV](http://www.open-mesh.org/), [OLSR](http://olsr.org/), [BMX](http://www.bmx6.net/) and [802.11s](http://open80211s.org/). These are all supported on OpenWRT which [supports a very large number of consumer wireless routers](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start)

There are also many large scale deployments such as [freifunk](http://en.freifunk.net) and deployments by [The Village Telco](http://villagetelco.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more info, batmand (layer 3) or batman-adv(layer 2) can run on almost anything with a resemblance of linux, I have managed to get it working on android devices (running cyanogenmod mostly), raspberry's, laptops, foneras, .... basically anything that has or allows a wireless card with ad-hoc mode and a linux-based operating system.

Comment: What did you have to do exactly to get batmand running on Android? (Other than rooting?)

Answer (score 0):

Freifunk Luebeck uses D-Link 300 with batman-adv